# choosing of Lyapunov function in solving a non-linear autonomous system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While choosing the V(X) for solving a non-linear autonomous system of equations, we have to see that it is a positive definite function and that it's derivative w.r.t. t is <=0 , always. But it is not always obvious to us how to choose it. Even in the theorem of checking the stability of critical points for such systems, it says that if there exists a Lyapunov function , so how do we know that such function exist and if it exists what will it be like, how do we construct such a function,. And is such a function unique?

Answer (score 1):

You can see Lyapunov's method as a generalization of the other stability criteria such as the minimum energy principle. The most important fact is to realize that the Lyapunov stability criterion is a sufficient condition.

Finding a Lyapunov function such that its derivative is non-positive ensures that at least your system is stable. But not finding this function does not imply that the system is unstable. It may be that you haven't come up with the right function yet, or even that it does not exist.

Finding these functions is based on intuition and mostly experience. And the function is not unique at all (you could always rescale for example).

Comment: If I can clarify something else let me know, otherwise let's accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is just hit and trial method , by which you choose the Lyapunov function. But with practice you will come to know about it. And regarding the uniqueness of the Lyapunov  function, no it is not unique , it can have any no. of Lyapunov function that satisfies the conditions.